# Что такое "дерево коммитов" в гите?

Tags: git, терминология

Прохожу гит и столкнулась с термином "дерево коммитов". Что имеется ввиду под этим термином?

Comment: к примеру [дерево](http://prntscr.com/sux5cg) через IDE VS.Так же можно ппглядеть и в командной строке ()будет не так красиво просто)

Comment: https://habr.com/ru/post/433748/ может немного поможет

Answer (score 2, accepted):

каждый коммит (кроме самого первого) в хранилище связан с «родительским» коммитом (или с несколькими в случае «коммита слияния»).

если воспользоваться терминологией из теории графов, и представить коммиты как узлы, а их связи — как рёбра, то получится **дерево**. правда, с циклами (которые образуются при слиянии). поэтому [строгому определению из теории графов](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%94%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%BE_(%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%BE%D1%80%D0%B8%D1%8F_%D0%B3%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%84%D0%BE%D0%B2)) оно не соответствует.

наглядно:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

изображение взято [отсюда](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/git-pocket-guide/9781449327507/ch01.html)